# How to get an RSS feed and not an Atom feed

Tags: support, feed

The feeds of the sites are Atom.
Example: [Feed of the tutorials tag in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=tutorials&sort=newest)

How to get an RSS Feed?

Twitter for example provides both versions:

- [twitter search Atom feed](http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=+something)
- [twitter search RSS feed](http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=+something)

Comment: Why do you need RSS and not Atom?

Comment: Laurence: Because of the reader my android app uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the feed through [Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com). That'll get you both flavors.